# How do I add Secrets Manager IAM permission?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

I'm reading the CDK docs about the [SecretsManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-secretsmanager-readme.html) and I'm not sure if I've mis-understood, but what I thought would work from their example doesn't seem to grant the permission I expected. Essentially I have a stack that contains some Lambdas, and I'd like all of them to be able to Read two secrets from the SecretsManager.

```
class CdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
    /**
     *
     * @param {cdk.Construct} scope
     * @param {string} id
     * @param {cdk.StackProps=} props
     */
    constructor(scope, id, props) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-new
        new APIServices(this, "APIServices");

        const role = new iam.Role(this, "SecretsManagerRead", {
            assumedBy: new iam.AccountRootPrincipal(),
        });

        const dbReadSecret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, "databaseReader");
        const dbWriteSecret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, "databaseWriter");

        dbReadSecret.grantRead(role);
        dbWriteSecret.grantRead(role);
    }
}
```

If I understood it correctly I should simply create this role and give it permissions to access secrets? My Lambda's still however failed when I tried to run them. Do I need to do anything else not mentioned in the docs I was reading about assigning that role to the Lambdas explicitly too?

Comment: Did you add this after the Lambda was deployed? If so it may have already assumed and would need to have assumed the role again. Also this code is creating the role but not associating it with a Lambda :(

Comment: Did you add this role to the Lambda function as its execution role?

Comment: I did add this after the lands was already deployed. @DennisTraub how would you go about associating the additional role with the Lamda?

Comment: A Lambda function can only assume one execution role. You would either have to add a policy with the above permissions to the existing role or replace the role attached to the existing Lambda function with your new one.

Comment: @DennisTraub thanks! Do you have any links to examples? Or if you pop an answer in with an example and it works then I can accept :)

Comment: I've created an answer, showing how you can add the permissions to the existing role.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on your actual context there are two possible variants.

**1. Import existing role**

If the Lambda function has been predefined (e.g. in a different stack), you can add the additional permissions to the existing Lambda execution role by importing it into this CDK stack first.

```
class CdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope, id, props) {
        // ...

        // Import the existing role into the stack
        const roleArn = 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyExistingLambdaExecutionRole'
        const role = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'Role', roleArn, {
            mutable: true,
        });

        const dbReadSecret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, "databaseReader");
        const dbWriteSecret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, "databaseWriter");

        dbReadSecret.grantRead(role);
        dbWriteSecret.grantRead(role);
    }
}
```

For more information regarding the usage of the `aws-iam` CDK module, [here's the link to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-iam-readme.html). [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html), you can learn more about the Lambda Execution Role itself.

**2. Lambda function defined as part of stack**

If the lambda function has been defined somewhere in this stack, you can simply attach the permissions to the Lambda function through its reference using `dbReadSecret.grantRead(lambda.role)` and `dbWriteSecret.grantRead(lambda.role)` respectively.

```
class CdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope, id, props) {
        // ...

        // Create the function or retrieve the reference if 
        // it has been defined somewhere else in the stack

        const lambda = ...

        const dbReadSecret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, "databaseReader");
        const dbWriteSecret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, "databaseWriter");

        dbReadSecret.grantRead(lambda.role);
        dbWriteSecret.grantRead(lambda.role);
    }
}
```

Please have a look at [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636929/specifying-a-custom-role-for-lambda-with-the-aws-cdk) for reference.

Comment: Thanks, so just a follow up. This is modifying the role write? How do I obtain the roleArn when this CDK stack itself is most likely creating that in the first place?

Comment: I understood that the Lambda function already existed. Which means there should be an existing role associated.

Comment: Please clarify if the Lambda function is part of the stack or if the Lambda function already exists.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. The APIServices defines both a Lamda function and an ApiGateway.

Comment: Then you can simply attach the permissions to the Lambda function through its reference using `dbReadSecret.grantRead(lambda.role)` and `dbWriteSecret.grantRead(lambda.role)` respectively.

Comment: Please have a look at the answer to this question for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636929/specifying-a-custom-role-for-lambda-with-the-aws-cdk

Comment: I've integrated my above comments into the answer.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look shortly and accept if it resolves my problem, which I think it will scanning it. CDK docs aren't that great I'm finding

Comment: Happy to help. Let me know if you there's still something missing. And regarding the documentation: It's an open source project, so please feel free to contribute ;-)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That worked, I had to use `Secret.fromSecretArn()` in the end as the secret wasn't part of the stack and I hadn't realised I was creating new ones. But basically the `grantRead` bit was the bit I was missing.

Comment: Great! Thanks for letting me know that you got it to work.

Comment: Just checked out your profile - I'm sure you'll be seeing a lot more of my questions over the coming weeks :D